# How do I display DATE in 'DD MON YYYY' format?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am a newbie for Oracle database programming and I wish to INSERT date (also display) in 'DD MON YYYY' format. (PS: This only involves INSERT event). Which data type (DATE or TIMESTAMP) is the most suitable option for me in order to accomplish this format? How was I supposed to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely you will need to "do so manually", i.e. use datepart + datepart + datepart.

Comment: What is the client in this case? I would use a DATE type in the database, and do all parsing and formatting on the client.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, if I select DATE type and inject 'INSERT INTO Table_Name VALUES (TO_DATE('27 Jun 2014', 'DD MON YYYY'));', the output will be '06/27/2014' rather than '27 Jun 2014' as expected.

Comment: You've missed my point. You shouldn't be sending it to or fetching it from the database as a string at all. Do all the text conversions at the client. We can't easily help you with that as you haven't told us what the client is.

Comment: Don't change the title of the question if it's answered. The fact that there is an accepted answer *will* mark this as "closed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DATE` column does not have any format.

So the format that you use when inserting or updating data is irrelevant for displaying that data (that's one of the reasons why you should never store a date in a `VARCHAR` column).

Any formatted output you see for a `DATE` column in your SQL tool (e.g. SQL*Plus) is applied by that tool. It is not part of the data stored in that column.

When providing a date literal you should either use the `to_date()` function with an explicit format mask:

```
insert into some_table (some_date_column)
values (to_date('27-06-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'));
```

I also do not recommend using formats with written month names (27-JUN-2014) when supplying a date literal because they *also* depend on the NLS settings of the client computer and might produce (random) errors due to different languages. Using numbers only is much more robust.

I prefer to use ANSI date literals because it's a bit less typing:

```
insert into some_table (some_date_column)
values (DATE '2014-06-27');
```

The format for an ANSI date (or timestamp) literal is *always* the ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd).

When you select your data you can display the date in whatever format you like. Either by using the `to_char()` function (e.g. when using a SQL tool) or using functions from your programming language (the preferred way to use inside an application):

```
select to_char(some_date_column,'dd-mon-yyyy')
from some_table;
```

Note that the `DATE` data type in Oracle (despite it's name) also stores the time. a `TIMESTAMP` does the same thing only with a higher precision (it includes milliseconds, whereas the `DATE` data type only stores seconds).

Comment: @user3781895: then you need to check the APEX settings for the default date format. As I said: a `DATE` is stored **without any format**. It's the application that applies that formatting (Oracle client tools tend to use the NLS settings from the environment variables - I don't know how APEX does it)

Comment: @user3781895 I have no experience with APEX, you will need to check the APEX manual (or ask another question on how to change the date display format in APEX)

Answer (score 0):

To **insert** a record,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (DATE_FIELD) VALUES (TO_DATE ('27-JUN-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

It is advisable to use DATE data-type until and unless you need the date's accuracy to be till milli seconds.  In your case, go with DATE datatype and TIMESTAMP is not necessary

To **select** a record,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_FIELD, 'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM TABLE_NAME;
```

In genral, remember this:

- **TO_DATE** is a function used to convert a string(CHAR) TO DATE
- **TO_CHAR** is a function used to convert a DATE to a string(CHAR)

Comment: How will the output be like that? Are you using the select query provided in my answer?

Answer (score -2):

In this scenario date datatype will be suitable for you, and for the desired format you should try like this:-

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(DATE_COLUMN) VALUES('27-JUN-2014');
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: That is a bad style. It relies on implicit data type conversion based on the NLS settings of the client and server. Your statement will e.g. fail on my computer.

Comment: But i have used date format always like this in oracle. and very frequently i have used this. And can you plz elaborate some more regarding this.