# How to convert the string type data into date format in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Sorry i am new to postgres.

Servlet gives me

UPDATED:
 **string** type in the form **07-Jul-2014**.

I have inserted some date in My db column using

```
 to_date('1963-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')//my column is of Date type
```

So how can i convert 07-Jul-2014 into 2014-06-07 so that i can save into my tables?

Comment: What data type is that column? "*string type date*" does not make sense. You also want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444971/how-do-i-display-date-in-dd-mon-yyyy-format

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: sorry i have edited now

Comment: You shouldn't be converting that string in SQL. You should be parsing the string in your servlet (e.g. using `SimpleDateFormat`) and then use a `PreparedStatement` and `setDate()` to send the date to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
to_date('07-Jul-2014', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'); Will return the result in Date format '2014-07-07'
```

Where '07-Jul-2014' is the string from your servlet.

Ref: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html